# reading from csv file in shell scripting

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv

I am running a script run.sh. 
The script is executed as follows. $./run.sh read.csv
The contents of the script are as follows.

```
   tail -n +2 $1 | while IFS="," read -r A B C D E F;
    do
        python test.py ${A} ${B} ${C} ${D} ${E} ${F}
    done
```

My question is "If i need to pass in additional command line arguments along with read.csv from the terminal like this (for Ex: `$./run.sh name sex DOB read.csv`) how do i modify the code so that it works fine.

Because if i pass any other command line arguments along with the file name(read.csv) i am getting access errors to the file read.csv

Comment: Why not just use python to parse csv

Answer (score 1):

Positional parameters is what you are after. This is how you can do it:

```
tail -n +2 $4 | while IFS="," read -r A B C D E F;##note now you would pass $4 to tail command which is your file name
do
    python test.py ${A} ${B} ${C} ${D} ${E} ${F}
done
```

You could access those values like name in $1, sex in `$2`, DOB with $3 and read.csv in $4